# How do I check a file's magic number (or hex signature) in R?

Tags: r, file, compression, bzip2

I'd like to detect the file type of an object in order to determine the right connection for a compressed file (e.g. whether to use `bzfile` `gzfile`, `xzfile` etc.  Obviously I could "guess" based on the file extension, but my understanding is that the checking the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) would be more robust (though I'm a little unclear if that's portable to Windows-based architectures?)

How do I return the magic number of a file to determine if it is, say, is indeed `BZh`?

Note that I'd like a solution that is suitable for use in package development; e.g. will be as portable as possible across operating systems and not specific to *nix systems.

Comment: can you just parse `system("file somefilename")` with the unix `file` util?

Comment: See edit above, my goal here is to get a solution that works across OS's that I could include in a package.

Comment: `file.exe` is included in Rtools

Comment: @r2evans you should write it up as an answer

Comment: cboettig, both answers seem relevant. Is there enough to be able to accept one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several packages on Github that make use of libmagic some way or other:

- https://github.com/hrbrmstr/wand: Wraps `libmagic` on *nix and uses `file.exe` from Rtools on Windows.
- https://github.com/hrbrmstr/simplemagic: R only solution using a subset from `magic.mgc`.
- https://github.com/daqana/dqmagic: Wraps `libmagic`on *nix and compiles `libmagic` on Windows (c.f. https://github.com/daqana/dqmagic/tree/windows)

Comment: Brilliant, nice summary and precisely what I was looking (hoping!) for.  Thanks much.

Comment: Is there any in CRAN?

Comment: @IndranilGayen wand has been submitted to CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/package=wand

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a package or function already written that does this natively in R.  Though I think it would be relatively straight-forward to scrape the wiki reference table (or get a copy of `magic.mgc` and parse it) and use `readBin` or similar, I think a more straight-forward method for cross-platform use is to use the `file` command. The only lack of cross-platform is on windows when Rtools is not available.

I created two files, creatively named "gz" and "bz2", and ran this test.

```
ptns <- list(gzip="gzip compressed data",
             bzip2="bzip2 compressed data",
             pdf15="PDF document, version 1.5",
             xlsx="Microsoft Excel")

files <- c("gz", "bz2")
out <- system2("file", args=files, stdout=TRUE)

setNames(sapply(out, function(o) {
  thistype <- "unk"
  for (j in seq_along(ptns)) {
    if (grepl(ptns[[j]], o)) {
      thistype <- names(ptns)[j]
      break
    }
  }
  thistype
}), files)
#      gz     bz2 
#  "gzip" "bzip2"
```

The reason I chose a `for` loop internally is that I wanted it to break execution once a successful match is made.